# Parse and replace @usernames and URL's within iphone app

Tags: objective-c, regex, ios, replace

I'm working on a twitter app, and need some help.  I would like to replace @usernames and URL's w/ bold blue text, and link to the corresponding views w/in my app.  I'm able to parse the tweet text, and construct an array with the @usernames and URL's, but i haven't figured out how to parse and replace the @usernames and URL's w/ stylized text inline.

Basically I would like the text to look similar the tweet text on the official Twitter app (aka Tweetie).

Here's an example of a tweet that I found on google. You will notice that the @usernames, and the links are blue:
http://www.tipb.com/images/stories/2009/02/twitter_celebs_iphone.jpg

I'm using GTMRegex from Google Toolbox for Mac for the regular expressions.

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)parseTweet {
NSString *text = message.text;
NSArray *a;

a = [text gtm_allSubstringsMatchedByPattern:@"@[[:alnum:]_]+"];
for (NSString *s in a) {
    NTLNURLPair *pair = [[NTLNURLPair alloc] init];
    pair.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", [s substringFromIndex:1]];
    pair.screenName = s;
    [links addObject:pair];
    [pair release];
}
a = [text gtm_allSubstringsMatchedByPattern:@"http:\\/\\/[^[:space:]]+"];
for (NSString *s in a) {
    NTLNURLPair *pair = [[NTLNURLPair alloc] init];
    pair.text = s;
    pair.url = s;
    [links addObject:pair];
    [pair release];
}
a = [text gtm_allSubstringsMatchedByPattern:@"https:\\/\\/[^[:space:]]+"];
for (NSString *s in a) {
    NTLNURLPair *pair = [[NTLNURLPair alloc] init];
    pair.text = s;
    pair.url = s;
    [links addObject:pair];
    [pair release];
}
```

}

Comment: What about your current code is not working for you?

Comment: @Ether i'm able to extract the @usernames and links by using the code above, but i haven't been able to figure out how to replace the text w/ blue links.

Comment: Styling text in iOS currently is not easy.  Are you comfortable with Core Text, if that is the case it’s doable but not before 3.2; Three20 has styled labels that might work for your case, or you can consider using a web view.

Comment: I guess most open source twitter clients for iPhone already does what you need. From top of my mind: NatsuLiphone  https://github.com/takuma104/ntlniph

Answer (score 0):

What type of ViewController do you use?
Don't know if I understand your problem right, but maybe it would help to use a UIWebView for displaying the content of your array.

Then you can easily include some local Stylesheet to style the links the way you want.